# cms tag inside a custom templatetag template doesn't work

Tags: django, django-templates, django-cms

I'm trying to call `show_menu` inside a custom templatetag template.
Something like:

```
base.html
xpto.html
    template that extends base.html and loads cms_tags and my_custom_tags

my_custom_tag_template.html loads cms_tags
    in this template I call {% show_menu %} and it doesn't work.
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Here's a good guide for [templatetags](http://www.mechanicalgirl.com/post/custom-template-tags-in-django/) make sure you've done everything right

Comment: Thanks! I'll read it.
The custom templatetag is working fine. The issue is when I want to call the show_menu tag, or any other cms tag inside my custom tag.